# Replace multiple columns to missing based on value of another column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation, missing-data

I would like an efficient way to replace values of many columns to `NA`if they are bigger than the value of a different column.

For example: replace all values in columns `height1:height5` with `NA` if these values are `>height6`

```
set.seed(1)

# example data
N <- 200
data <- data.frame(id = 1:N,
               height1 = rnorm(N,50:60),
               height2 = rnorm(N,60:70),
               height3 = rnorm(N,70:80),
               height4 = rnorm(N,80:90),
               height5 = rnorm(N,90:100),
               height6 = rnorm(N,60:110))
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. If Row 1 looks like [1,55,65,75,85,95,90] Then `height5` is greater than `height6`, so do you want to replace all values in `height5` with NA, or just the value on that row? And do you want to replace all values in the row with NA (like `height1, height2, ..., height5`) with NA? Please be more specific by giving an example, if needed.

Comment: I would like to replace just the value for the row for the specific column that are greater than height6. I.e for row 1 the value of height5 would be NA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can do

```
data %>% mutate_at(
   vars(height1:height5),
   ~ifelse(.x > data$height6, NA, .x)
   )
```